# Sum up hours based 2 criteria (2 rows)

Tags: excel

I am trying to sum up the hours worked on each of the tasks for a particular person for a 3-day period (see below screenshot). What is the most dynamic way to build the formula in excel? Thank you!

[sum up hours based on two categories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O1Pu7.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Can the data be normalized or does it have to stay in this awkward structure?  If you can normalize the data, you can solve easily with SUMIFS. 
Normalization would mean a simple 4-column structure: Date, Task, Person, Hours.

Date     Task     Person     Hours

Jan-1    i         A          0.5

Jan-1    ii        B          1.5

Answer (score 0):

For your example data, you can paste this into cells C13:C16

```
=SUMIFS($3:$3,$1:$1,RIGHT(B13,LEN(B13)-FIND(" ",B13)),$2:$2,RIGHT($A$13,LEN($A$13)-FIND(" ",$A$13)))+SUMIFS($6:$6,$4:$4,RIGHT(B13,LEN(B13)-FIND(" ",B13)),$5:$5,RIGHT($A$13,LEN($A$13)-FIND(" ",$A$13)))+SUMIFS($9:$9,$7:$7,RIGHT(B13,LEN(B13)-FIND(" ",B13)),$8:$8,RIGHT($A$13,LEN($A$13)-FIND(" ",$A$13)))
```